# how can i insert date in yyyy-mm-dd format into flex

Tags: adobe, flexbuilder, flex3

I have to select date from date field in flex and store that date into SqlLite database. I
 am inserting date by using this code :

dbInsertDate = datechooser.selectedDate.getFullYear().toString()+'0'+(datechooser.selectedDate.getMonth()+1).toString()+"-0"+datechooser.selectedDate.getDate().toString();

where dbInsertDate is string type variable and datechooser is date field id. It stores the date in database in a format like 2455361.5. I want to store date in either dd-mm-yyyy format or yyyy-mm-dd format in the database. How can i store date in yyyy-mm-dd format in SqlLite using flex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:** Convert date to string and in yyyy mm dd format

**code:**

here date will be like this string 2011-02-15

`enter code here`dateChooser is datefield.

public var dbInsertDate:String;

private var selectedDateByUser:int;

if(dateChooser.selectedDate.getMonth() < 9)

{

```
if(dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate() < 10)
{
    dbInsertDate = 
    dateChooser.selectedDate.getFullYear().toString()+'-0'+(dateChooser.selectedDate.getMonth()+1).toString()+"-0"+dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate().toString();
}
else
{
    dbInsertDate = 
    dateChooser.selectedDate.getFullYear().toString()+'-0'+(dateChooser.selectedDate.getMonth()+1).toString()+"-"+dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate().toString();

}
```

else
{

```
if(dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate() < 10)
{
    dbInsertDate = 
    dateChooser.selectedDate.getFullYear().toString()+'-'+(dateChooser.selectedDate.getMonth()+1).toString()+"-0"+dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate().toString();
}
else

{
    dbInsertDate = 
    dateChooser.selectedDate.getFullYear().toString()+'-'+(dateChooser.selectedDate.getMonth()+1).toString()+"-"+dateChooser.selectedDate.getDate().toString();
}
```

}

here date will be like this string 20110215. so you can store date in this format at varchar column type in sqqlite.

```
enter code here
```

var dateArray:Array = new Array();

dateArray = dbInsertDate.split('-');

selectedDateByUser = dateArray[0]+dateArray[1]+dateArray[2];

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DateFormatter:

```
var formatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
formatter.formatString = "DD-MM-YYYY";
var result:String = formatter.format(datechooser.selectedDate);
```

If you use localization you can "translate" the format string to the needed format.